# I am not sure which one is correct way to plot graph for T_n=cos⁡(2nπ/1000)

Tags: r

I have typed the coding for the function *T_n=cos⁡(2nπ/1000)* in **r**. But not sure which one is correct.

The question requires to plot 3 graph which are:

(1) Plot T_n for n=1,2,…,1000.

(2) Plot 1000(T_n-T_(n-1)) for n=2,3,…,1000.

(3) Plot 1000^3(T_n-3T_(n-1)+3T_(n-2)-T_(n-3)) for n=4,5,…,1000.

I have tried plot for (1) and (2) both I got a straight line

(1)

```
n = c(1:1000)
T.n = cos((2*n*pi))/1000    # I'm not sure if it's this or this T.n=cos((2*n*pi)/1000)
plot(T.n)
```

(2)

```
n=c(2:1000)
T.n=cos(2*n*pi)/1000
x=1000
T_n=1000*(T.n[2:x]-T.n[1:(x-1)])
```

So according to *T.n = cos((2*n*pi))/1000* I get a *straight line* graph and this *T.n=cos((2*n*pi)/1000)* I get a *U shaped* graph. I am still confuse which one is correct.

Comment: You're getting a straight line with `cos(2*n*pi)/1000` because your vector, `n`, is a series of whole numbers. Calculating cos(2kπ), where k is any whole number, is equal to 1. Divide `cos(2*n*pi)` by 1000 using `n=1:1000` yields a series of identical values—all being 0.001, giving you a straight line. You want `cos(2 * n * π / 1000)`. Your graph will look vaguely U-shaped, but it will actually be a cosine curve ranging from 1 to -1 to 1 on the y axis as n goes from 1 to 1000 on the x axis. Use `plot(T.n, type='l')` and it will look better.

Comment: Plot 1000^3(T_n-3T_(n-1)+3T_(n-2)-T_(n-3)) for n=4,5,…,1000..How about for this equation how do I do the coding in r for this? Also which answer is actually correct the straight line graph or the cosine graph.